# Callback validation with parameter using Codeigniter and setting rules using an Array?

Tags: codeigniter, callback, validation

I want to use a function to validate dates with a parameter...but I have all validations in a config array.

```
config = array(
'page1/send'   => array(
    array(
            'field' => 'name',
            'label' => 'lang:name',
            'rules' => 'required'
         )
),    

'page2/send'   => array(
                            array(
                                    'field' => 'name',
                                    'label' => 'lang:name',
                                    'rules' => 'required'
                            ),
                             array(
                                    'field' => 'date1',
                                    'label' => 'lang:date',
                                    'rules' => 'required|'
                            )
                            array(
                                    'field' => 'date2',
                                    'label' => 'lang:date',
                                    'rules' => 'required|callback_date_compare'
                            )

                        ),
```

I would like to pass an additional parameter to "callback_date_compare" in this case the other field (date1).

Without setting the rules in an array I could do it in this way if "$date1" is the value of the post['date1'] and it worked perfectly :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('date2', 'lang:date', 'required|callback_date_compare[' . $date1 . ']');
```

I need to do it inside the array because I have all validations inside it and I tried to do it the same way inside the $config array but it didn´t work, something like:

```
                                  array(
                                        'field' => 'date2',
                                        'label' => 'lang:date',
                                        'rules' => 'required|callback_date_compare[date1]'
                                )
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your config array

```
array(
        'field' => 'date2',
        'label' => 'lang:date',
        'rules' => 'required|callback_date_compare[date1]'
   )
```

in your date compare callback

```
function date_compare($value, $field_name)
{
    // Get the value in the field
    $field = $_POST[$field_name];

    if ($value != $this->input->post($field))
    {
          $this->form_validation->set_message('date_compare', 'Dates are different');
          return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
         return TRUE;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your config is global, it might be a good idea to have the function global aswell.

Create `MY_Form_validation.php` in `libraries/` :

```
<?php

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    function date_compare($str_start, $str_key) {

        $bool   =   ($str_start == $this->input->post($str_key));
        if ( ! $bool)
            $this->form_validation->set_message('date_compare', 'Dates are different');

        return $bool;

    }

}
```

---

Then set the rule `date_compare[date1]`.

Comment: Actually I have the function date_compare in My_controller to use it from any controller. Thanks anyway Robin.

Comment: Hmm I wonder what happends if you use `site.com/date_compare` then?

Comment: With site.com/date_compare Returns 404 Pagen Not Found" and with site.com/date_compare(param1, param2) returns "An Error Was Encountered  The URI you submitted has disallowed characters."

Comment: site.com/any_controler/date_compare will work - but it doenst matter- just append an "underscore" to "date_compare" to make it private - and then change your callback to "callback__date_compare" (note the double underscore)

Answer (score 0):

create a function called date_compare:

```
public function date_compare($date2)
{

if ($date2 != $this->input->post("date1"))
{
$this->form_validation->set_message('date_compare', 'Dates are different');
return FALSE;
}
else
{
return TRUE;
}

}
```

config:

```
'page2/send'   => array(
                            array(
                                    'field' => 'name',
                                    'label' => 'lang:name',
                                    'rules' => 'required'
                            ),
                             array(
                                    'field' => 'date1',
                                    'label' => 'lang:date',
                                    'rules' => 'required|'
                            )
                            array(
                                    'field' => 'date2',
                                    'label' => 'lang:date',
                                    'rules' => 'required|callback_date_compare'
                            )

                        ),
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, the problem is I would like to use the function in other´s forms and I want it to be "generic". If I do it as you say I can´t change the name of the input.. date1, date2, etc.. The function I have is to compare two dates ( start and end) and control that the "start" date not greater than "end", but I use it in other places